# Not created again already exists material

Tags: python, scripting

I have a such a code

```
    for image in bpy.data.images:
        if image.users:
            continue
        bpy.data.images.remove(image)
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
    if mat is True:                
        mat.use_nodes=False   
        bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.delete(bpy.data.materials['Material'])                                 
    if mat is None:
    # create material
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")
    mat.use_nodes=True
    nodes=mat.node_tree.nodes
    for node in nodes:
        nodes.remove(node)    
    principledBDSF = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled') 
    principledBDSF.inputs[0].default_value = 0.8, 0.11, 0.02, 1
    principledBDSF.inputs[4].default_value = 0.5    
    principledBDSF.inputs[5].default_value = 0.45 
    principledBDSF.inputs[7].default_value = 0.35                     
    LCAoutput = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial') 
    LCAoutput.location = 300,0    
    links = mat_LCA.node_tree.links
    link = links.new(principledBDSF.outputs[0], LCAoutput.inputs[0])                      
    bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(bpy.data.materials['Material'])
```

When I run this function, I create material, but when I run it again, this material is created again. I am curious how to make the material not created as it already exists.
Greets

Answer (score 3):

**A material never `is True`.**

Use `if mat:` which is boolean true if not `None`  Using `if mat is True:`  for a material will never be true.

Since you are setting use nodes later can also do this

```
mat = materials.get("Foo") or materials.new("Foo")
```

To drill this in here is a simple example

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

def main(context):
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Foo")
    if mat:
        print("Material Foo exists, skipping")
        return 
    else:
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Foo")
        print("Created Material Foo")
        # do something with new material
        
    return

# test calls

main(context)
main(context)
main(context)
```

Output from default file no material "Foo"

```
Created Material Foo
Material Foo exists, skipping
Material Foo exists, skipping
```

Comment: Thanks :-) And If i want do nothing with this material. Go to next step > if mat_LCA : > mat_LCA = bpy.data.materials.get("LCA Material") > mat_LCA.use_nodes=False

Comment: As your Q code stands the line `mat.use_nodes = True`  will always be run, regardless of any prior setting. Perhaps add a return if the material already exists.  (or indenting is incorrect above)

Comment: Without it, in Blender Use nodes will be turn off. I want just make, that if I'm pressing button again, the next this same material will not created.

Comment: I know how it works.  Please review your question code.  Perhaps the line `mat.use_nodes = True` and every line below needs to be indented one tab right to bring it under the if material is none clause.  Can only go by code posted.

Comment: Ok I made one step forward. Now I have error in line 216 for node in nodes: and I have such a error line 216, in execute UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nodes' referenced before assignment

Comment: AFAIC this has answered the question (as it was when answered)   You are describing a basic syntax error that is telling you that the code is getting to line 216 at which point `nodes` is still undefined.

Comment: I fixed it but still I have this same problem.  I don't want to re-create the same material as it already exists. At the moment, this happens when I run the code again.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you fixed it. Added mega simple example that either creates a material "Foo" or does nothing.

Comment: Ok, few steps forward, but know I have such a error Function.result expectd a set, not a NoneType

Comment: This no longer has anything to do with this question / answer.  Error suggests: A return from an operator has to be a set showing the return status  eg `{'FINISHED'}` (all good)  or `{'CANCELLED}` (failed for some reason, eg material already exists)  Please search for these, or follow some simple examples given in  blenders text editor templates or the docs.  As stated, this answer answers your question as posted.  It is not my or anyone elses "job" to work thru this with you.  If you come to an impasse ask another question. (A question not a question in a comment)